# Multi Column Set Null Value

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have the following SQL Statement, which gives me an error.

```
UPDATE GNGRB.BS_CLOSING 
SET ENDINGDATE + STATUS + STATUSDATE = NULL 
WHERE UNIT = '231296' AND BMON = '2020114';
```

What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For a start, you could have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
What is your question? Can you post the error you are getting?
Is there a specific problem with your current implementation?
What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can update multiple columns like that:

```
UPDATE GNGRB.BS_CLOSING
SET ENDINGDATE = NULL
    ,STATUS = NULL
    ,STATUSDATE = NULL
WHERE UNIT = '231296'
    AND BMON = '2020114';
```

Comment: Any more query ?? i want to be one time NULL type but this query three time NULL type.

Comment: You can't set three columns to NULL by typing NULL only once. Also, this is just syntax, it does not affect performance.